# Insert Query adding to database but not appearing in ListView after insert until page is refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net

As part of a registration page, users can add their address, if they have not got an address the `EmptyItemTemplate` within my `ListView` control commands users to click a button outside of the `ListView` control to add an address which is shown below;

```
<asp:Button ID="add_new_address" CssClass="blue" runat="server" Text="Add New Address" OnClick="add_new_address_Click" />
<div id="add_address_div" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="address_dropdown_insert" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Home">Home Address</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Term">Term Time Address</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Mail">Mail Address</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Business">Business Address</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList><br />
        Address 1:
        <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="address_1TextBox" /><br />
        Address 2:
        <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="address_2TextBox" /><br />
        Town/City:
        <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="town_cityTextBox" /><br />
        County:
        <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="countyTextBox" /><br />
        PostCode:
        <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="postcodeTextBox" /><br />
        Country:
        <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="countryTextBox" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ID="InsertButton" OnClick="insert_address_button_Click" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" ID="Button4" OnClick="cancel_address_button_Click" /><br />
</div>
```

I then have the following code behind in C# which inserts the data from the insert form above into a database table;

```
protected void add_new_address_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        add_address_div.Visible = true;
        add_new_address.Visible = false;
    }
protected void insert_address_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string userid = Session["user_id"].ToString();
        string addtype = address_dropdown_insert.SelectedValue;
        string add1 = address_1TextBox.Text;
        string add2 = address_2TextBox.Text;
        string town = town_cityTextBox.Text;
        string county = countyTextBox.Text;
        string pcode = postcodeTextBox.Text;
        string country = countryTextBox.Text;

        string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        myConnection.Open();

        String query = "INSERT INTO address (user_id, address_type, address_1, address_2, town_city, county, postcode, country) VALUES (@user_id, @address_type, @address_1, @address_2, @town_city, @county, @postcode, @country)";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", userid);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_type", addtype);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_1", add1);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_2", add2);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@town_city", town);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@county", county);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", pcode);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country);

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myConnection.Close();


    }

    protected void cancel_address_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        add_address_div.Visible = false;
    }
```

This works, in that data is inserted into the database table as it should but after I click the `insert_address_button`, the data does not display in the `ListView` control, it only displays the `EmptyItemTemplate`. However, if I were to refresh the page the data then appear.

I am also working within `View` Controls so a normal refresh will bring the user back to the beginning of the registration process and would prefer they would be redirected back to the `View` control for the Address'.

Is there a step in the process I am missing after the insert so that the data displays in the list view? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What code are you using to load the ListView data in the first place? You basically need to query the DB again to load the new results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to rebind the ListView's datasource. It's still got the "old" version.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still kinda new to C#, is this a fairly simple process with one or two lines of code or is this something that requires some research?

Comment: You've already bound to the ListView in order to originally display it. LV.Datasource = <something>, and LV.DataBind()

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much. In case anyone has a similar issue the code I used was `user_address.DataBind();
 address_list.DataBind();`

Answer (score 0):

You need the list to update asynchronously from the page when an address is added.  You can either have it re-load via Ajax or you can have a javascript function add the address that is being sent to the server side code to the list.